# How can I implode() only one column from a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, implode

I have array in following format:

```
Array
(
    [sales] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 6
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 8
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 25
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 34
                )

        )

)
```

Using:

```
foreach ($data['sales'] as $k => $row) {
    $list = implode(",",$row);
}
```

I get the following as output:

```
1,62,83,254,34
```

But I only need the second values from each subArray. The expected result needs to be:

```
6,8,25,34
```

How can I remove the first set of values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like `array_column()` but if you don't have PHP >= 5.5.0:

```
$list = implode(',', array_map(function($v) { return $v[1]; }, $data['sales']));
```

Or with the `foreach`:

```
foreach ($data['sales'] as $row) {
    $list[] = $row[1];
}
$list = implode(',', $list);
```

Comment: I think this would sounds better: *but if you don't have PHP >= 5.5.0*, [see my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2844319/abracadaver).

Answer (score 7):

Just grab the first column from your array with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), so that you end up with an array, e.g.

```
Array (
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 25
    [3] => 34
)
```

And [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it then as you already did, e.g.

```
echo implode(",", array_column($data["sales"], 1));
```

output:

```
6,8,25,34
```